# In macOS Mojave, is there a list of unused keyboard combinations for shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I am trying to define a new shortcut for "Select the previous input source", since the default shortcut (Control + Space) is conflicting with another app I need to use. Is there any table with a list of unused shortcuts in Mojave that could be good candidates for custom shortcuts? I am trying to find a balance between good usability (not having to stretch the hand in awkward positions to type the shortcut) and avoiding conflicts with already existing shortcuts.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, I think the difficulty is that you're asking about keyboard combinations for shortcuts in macOS Mojave, but the conflict you're describing is actually with a keyboard combinations used by a 3rd party app. So, getting a list of all keyboard combinations  isn't a trivial exercise if you need to know what they are across all apps. Or am I misreading your question?

Comment: What are your input sources?  If one is Latin and one non-Latin,you can use caps lock to switch by checking a preference box.

Comment: How about command plus space?  That used to be apple’s default.  If it conflicts, change the other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any table with a list of unused shortcuts in Mojave that could be good candidates for custom shortcuts?

There is not. There are a few utilities out there which will show you which key combinations *are* in use¹ but none (that I am aware of) show you *available* keyboard shortcuts.

¹ *I believe [KeyCue](https://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/) is the most well-known and best supported.*

One common method among Mac power users is the use of a [Hyper Key](https://brettterpstra.com/2019/05/10/did-your-hyper-key-break/) which is (generally speaking) where you remap holding down the Caps Lock key to equal holding down ⌘ ⇧ ⌥ ⌃ because few apps *(and few macOS default shortcuts)* use all 4 modifiers *(mostly because it is awkward to try to press them all at once, which is why remapping the Caps Lock key is recommended).*

Personally, I use a Hyper Key with [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) because, unlike shortcuts defined in System Preferences, Keyboard Maestro's shortcuts are easy to backup/restore, and easy to sync across multiple Macs.

Comment: The “hyper” key - good one... plus 1. Better than the “any” key as in “press any key”...